Quantification of KL divergence error for approximating a distribution over discrete random variables
I would like to know the following which has been stated in some literature, but never explicitly proved
Consider a setup consisting of a binary vector of random variables of length n say $\vec{v}=(v_0,v_1,v_2....v_n)$ where each $v_i \in \{1,-1\}$. Let us define an arbitrary distribution defined over such a support of $2^n$ random $\vec{v}$ vectors as $P(\vec{v}): \{-1,1\}^n \mapsto [0,1]$. The claim is it is always possible to approximately express $P(\vec{v})$ as an exponential of a multilinear polynomial of degree k as follows
\begin{equation}
P(\vec{v}) \approx e^{A(\vec{v})}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
A(\vec{v}) = a_0 + \sum_i c_i v_i + \sum_{i,j, i\ne j} K_{ij} v_i v_j + \sum_{i,j,p, i\ne j\ne p} H_{ijp} v_i v_jv_p + .....\sum_{i,j,p,q.... i\ne j\ne p\ne q ....} G_{ijpq....k} v_i v_jv_pv_q....v_k
\end{equation}
and $a_0$, $\vec{c}$, $\vec{K}$, $\vec{H}$,...$\vec{G}$ are all defined over real field. Is this claim always true ? How does one prove it? How does one quantify the error in KL divergence between the RHS and LHS of the first equation? Any formal proof, references, proof sketch will be really appreciated.

Your notation is strange, making it difficult to understand the question.  Evidently "${1,-1}$" is a set with two elements.  But then so would "${0,1}$" be, implying that your "arbitrary" distributions are all degenerate, placing all their probability on single points--but I doubt that's what you mean.  Concerning the question, the polynomials of degree $2^n$ span the set of all real-valued functions $P,$ so there's not much of a question of approximation: expressing $\log P$ as a polynomial, using extremely negative values to stand in for $\log 0,$ will be an excellent approximation.

Hi @whuber- Thanks for your answer. Yes, there was a typo in the notation which I fixed now. Concerning your answer, the multilinear polynomial above is defined over binary variables i.e. consists of monomials of the type $v_i$, $v_iv_j$ etc as opposed to monomials of real variables say $x, x^2, x^3$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I know the latter set is linearly independent, but  I am not aware of the result that monomials of binary variables also span the space of real-valued functions ? Can you point me to a source with proof ? what is the error in KL div for replacing log0 with negative values

Binary variables are perforce real, too.  It is usual to prove these results in college algebra courses.  One standard proof gives an algorithm for constructing a polynomial that agrees with the indicator function of a single point.  A linear combination of those indicator functions then does the job.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial for instance.
